# Project Euler 2 python3

Tags: python

I've got, what I think is a valid solution to [problem 2](http://projecteuler.net/problem=2) of Project Euler (finding all even numbers in the Fibonacci sequence up to 4,000,000). This works for lower numbers, but crashes when I run it with 4,000,000. I understand that this is computationally difficult, but shouldn't it just take a long time to compute rather than crash? Or is there an issue in my code?

```
import functools

def fib(limit):
    sequence = []
    for i in range(limit):
    if(i < 3):
        sequence.append(i)
    else:
        sequence.append(sequence[i-1] + sequence[i-2])
    return sequence

def add_even(x, y):
    if(y % 2 == 0):
        return x + y
    return x + 0

print(functools.reduce(add_even,fib(4000000)))
```

Comment: do you have to use longs or is that built into python?

Comment: Please post the traceback you get.

Comment: maybe you're out of RAM ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is about getting the Fibonacci numbers that are smaller than 4000000. Your code tries to find the first 4000000 Fibonacci values instead. Since Fibonacci numbers grow exponentially, this will reach numbers too large to fit in memory.

You need to change your function to stop when the last calculated value is more than 4000000.

Another possible improvement is to add the numbers as you are calculating them instead of storing them in a list, but this won't be necessary if you stop at the appropriate time.

Comment: This is the issue, but I think you're too pessimistic.  Even fib(4000000) only has ~836000 digits, so the numbers will never get too big to store in memory (since you'd only need to store a few). If that were the question, anyway, which as you point out it's not. :^)

Comment: Thanks, I had misunderstood the problem. I got the answer. However, I still don't see why my program crashed trying to calculate the sum of the even first 4000000 numbers.